# Op-Amp current sense in H-Bridge

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement, h-bridge

this is my first attempt ever at building an H bridge for brushed DC motors. The board is controlled externally with an Arduino that sends the EN and PWM signals. I also need to measure the motor current to do torque/current control.
For current sensing I decided to adopt low-side sensing with shunt resistor (10mOhm) and op-amp in non-inverting configuration to amplify the voltage drop.

The bridge-part of the board works quite as expected, I'm able to move a dc motor in both directions with varying duty cycle, but I have 2 problems:

1. Not crucial, but I noticed that the Green LED (I put it in order to signal that the board is powered) turns on even when the VBATT is disconnected if I apply the EN signal from the Arduino, and I really can't understand why.
2. Current sensing is not working. When I just power the circuit with a DC power supply I have 0.08A drawn by the op-amp. If I remove the IC, the current goes to 0. If I apply PWM, at 0.27A drawn from the supply (of which 0.19A = 0.27A-0.08A are due to the motor) I have:

- 1.9mV across the shunt resistor (which is reasonable, at 0.19A * 10mOhm)
- 1.9mV on the opamp non inverting input (of course)
- 0.42V on the opamp inverting input (?). This value is more or less fixed varying duty cycle.
- 10.63V on opamp out (?). This value is more or less fixed varying duty cycle.

Moreover, the op-amp gets rather hot in few seconds.
I already double checked the pcb for shorts or wrong connections.
To measure I'm using a multimeter since at the moment I don't have an oscilloscope at hand, planning on buying one.

So the questions are:

1. Why is the green LED turning ON when it is not supposed to
2. Why is the op-amp amplifier not working as expected
3. If possible, some recommendations on better ways/components for current sensing.

PS. At the moment I considered only through hole components for ease of soldering, but for future versions I will probably consider also SMD components.

[image: Brushed DC motor H Bridge schematic]

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to ground the unused *Output* of the 2nd half of your opamp?

Comment: To be honest, no. I did it without thinking too much. In next designs I would use the other OA as a voltage follower, or change OA altogether using a single channel CMOS rail-to-rail OA as suggested in other answer (something like TLV271)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Why is the green LED turning ON when it is not supposed to
> ```

Failure to recognize ESD input clamp to Vdd is powering up the 12V rail with logic input voltage. ( bad idea and cause for latch-up fault possible)

> ```
> Why is the op-amp amplifier not working as expected
> ```

Failure to read datasheets V common mode input range is +/-12 for +/15V supply (meaning required input must exceed bottom rail by 3V for biasing.

> ```
> If possible, some recommendations on better ways/components for current sensing.
> ```

- Use equal balanced resistors to shift both inputs near V/2 and achieve same gain.
- choose Rsense for approx 50mV full scale for worst case locked rotor current. due to power dissipation.  Usually choose Pd of R at 50% of rated value for ~70'C rise.
  -Consider braking current (BEMF) is negative , consider Vout=idle at Vref/2 to measure bipolar currents, if you want otherwise not
- Consider CMOS OA for Rail to Rail input and output but observe ESD precautions and latchup protection of moving motor and power off then ON

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the recommendations. Now I think I fully understand the op-amp common mode issue and how I could possibly solve it maintaining this design. 
However I do not understand the ESD issue, who is powering the 12V rail, why it happens only when EN is active, how could I properly change the design to "observe ESD precautions and latchup protection".

Comment: stray inductive noise from motor wires can be reduced using twisted pairs.  Your schematic cannot show all the wire inductive or crosstalk without a photo of layout 10nH/cm. This can create more voltage than the resistor depending on layout. thus raising the differential input RK’s on both sides with int/ext clamp Sch diodes to rails will prevent overshoot